# How can I convert sbyte[] to base64 string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, arrays, base64

How can I convert `sbyte[]` to base64 string?

I cannot convert that `sbyte[]` to a `byte[]`, to keep interoperability with java.

Comment: How do you want it converted to base64? Treat the sbyte as if it were a byte?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You absolutely *can* convert the `sbyte[]` to a `byte[]` - I can pretty much guarantee you that the Java code will *really* be treating the byte array as unsigned. (Or to put it another way: base64 is only *defined* in terms of unsigned bytes...)

Just convert to `byte[]` and call `Convert.ToBase64String`. Converting to `byte[]` is actually really easy - although C# itself doesn't provide a conversion between the two, the CLR is quite happy to perform a reference conversion, so you just need to fool the C# compiler:

```
sbyte[] x = { -1, 1 };
byte[] y = (byte[]) (object) x;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(y));
```

If you want to have a *genuine* `byte[]` you can copy:

```
byte[] y = new byte[x.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(x, 0, y, 0, y.Length);
```

but personally I'd stick with the first form.

Comment: Quick. Somebody throw me a link to john skeet facts. Just kidding. Respect.

Comment: It does make sense, as the Convert.ToBase64String uses pointers to get the binary representation... And it is a pattern...

Comment: @NoProblemBabe: I mean that it would make sense whether or not Convert.ToBase64String used pointers. That's an internal implementation detail.

Comment: @NoProblemBabe: No, you said: "It does make sense, as the Convert.ToBase64String uses pointers to get the binary representation" - I'm saying that the fact that `Convert.ToBase64String` uses pointers is *completely irrelevant* to my answer making sense.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        sbyte[] signedByteArray = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
        byte[] unsignedByteArray = (byte[])(Array)signedByteArray; 
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(unsignedByteArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate, using that dual casting quite often i receive an error about a mismatch array type. Specially using nhibernate. But thanks

Comment: I've seen that ther's a convertall method in the Array class, where you can, by lambda, cast each item